# What does "pane" mean in Example of Angular ContentChild referecens?

Tags: angular

In the reference:
[API > @angular/core > ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild)

The below is the snippet of example code.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
    <tab>
      <pane id="1" *ngIf="shouldShow"></pane>
      <pane id="2" *ngIf="!shouldShow"></pane>
    </tab>

    <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
  `,
})
```

What does "pane" in the line mean?

```
<pane id="1" *ngIf="shouldShow"></pane>
```

I suspect some definition is missing in this example.

Comment: "pane" is a "component" or a "directive". When you use ContentChildren (or ViewChildren) you can use as "selector" the class of one component (not the selector), the class of the directive (not the directive) or a template referenceVariable -a `#name` in .html you use @ContentChildren('name')-

Answer (score 0):

It's a custom directive only used in that example. You can see it in the following link:

https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild#example

Answer (score 0):

Here, the "pane" tag is a Directive, it's a wrapper for some logic

Come to think of Directives as "Components without templates"